# How to work around a HRTB bug?

Tags: rust, higher-rank-types

This snippet does not compile because of a [compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27863):

```
struct Theory<'a, T: 'a> {
    left: &'a T,
}

pub struct Contain<'a, T: 'a, U>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    for<'x> <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<&'x U>,
{
    theory: Theory<'a, T>,
    right: U,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a, U> Drop for Contain<'a, T, U>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    for<'x> <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<&'x U>,
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        //TODO
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I need this because I must compare the iterator `Item`s with `U`; but `Item` is a reference type, because I call `into_iter()` in a borrowed collection.

I then tried something like this to work around:

```
struct Theory<'a, T: 'a> {
    left: &'a T,
}

pub struct Contain<'a, 'b: 'a, T: 'a, U: 'b>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<&'b U>,
{
    theory: Theory<'a, T>,
    right: U,
    _marker: ::std::marker::PhantomData<&'b ()>,
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: 'a, U> Drop for Contain<'a, 'b, T, U>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<&'b U>,
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for left in self.theory.left.into_iter() {
            if left == &self.right {
                return;
            }
        }
        //handle case where all lefts are different of right
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

But I got a:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:22:24
   |
22 |             if left == &self.right {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
```

How can I iterate over `left`, then compare each elements with `right`?

Comment: Try to compile it with nightly, but then you will get a different error. I don't know if it correlates with the compiler bug, but I do think, that is an error in your code?

Comment: @hellow The error message is exactly the same in stable and nightly

Comment: Your original code also has a couple of bugs in it anyway. You don't actually use the lifetime `'x`. Changing that line to `for<'x> <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<&'x U>` _should_ work, except that the compiler will reject impls of `Drop` that have stricter bounds than the struct definition. The problem with an existentially quantified lifetime is that it cannot be compared to another because they are unknown. So It think it is _probably_ reasonable that the compiler would reject this.

Comment: @PeterHall This is labeled as a bug in the linked issue...

Comment: @Boiethios Yes. But I'm not _convinced_ that it is. Or at least, I can see why the restrictions on Drop impls would interact with HRTB like that. The restriction may just be framed the wrong way, and should be just to ensure that there are not instances of the struct for which  `Drop` is accidentally not implemented.

Comment: Your original code showed a different error

Comment: @hellow I only changed the second snippet, not the first one

Comment: Then I am wrong :D indeed. Silly me, I apologize

Answer (score 3):

You can simply require the trait bound `PartialEq<B>`. The methods `eq` and `ne` from the trait take all arguments by reference, so there is no reason why requiring `PartialEq` for a reference to a type.

So this works:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T: 'a, U> Drop for Contain<'a, 'b, T, U>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    <(&'a T) as IntoIterator>::Item: PartialEq<U>,  // <-- change 1 
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for left in self.theory.left.into_iter() {
            if left == self.right {                 // <-- change 2
                return;
            }
        }
        //handle case where all lefts are different of right
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, about your last note, it was a typo, I deleted it.